# Advantage to running SELECT DISTINCT to SELECT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

So I am fairly new to SQL and have been tasked with revamping/documenting programs at my current internship.

To cut to the chase, I am running the following query on a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as NumofAccounts 
    FROM Accounts 
        WHERE Deleted = 0 
        AND Account_ID In ( SELECT DISTINCT Account_ID FROM Tasks WHERE Deleted = 0 );
```

which yields a result of NumofAccounts = 18.

However the original query was:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as NumofAccounts 
        FROM Accounts 
            WHERE Deleted = 0 
            AND Account_ID In ( SELECT Account_ID FROM Tasks WHERE Deleted = 0 );
```

Both of these queries yield NumofAccounts = 18, however, if one isolates this part of the query:

```
SELECT Account_ID FROM Tasks WHERE Deleted = 0;
```

There are 736 rows of results, many of which are duplicate Account_IDs.

But if one adds DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Account_ID FROM Tasks WHERE Deleted = 0;
```

There are only 18 rows of results, which jibes with the NumofAccounts.

Is there any way of analyzing the runtime or efficiency discrepancy between these two queries?

Sorry for the long-winded post!

Comment: The `DISTINCT` will perform slower due to the automatic creation of an in memory index on `Account_ID`. There's no need to use `DISTINCT` in combination with an `IN` statement.

Comment: For reference, take a look at the estimated and actual execution plans for queries: [(MSDN: execution plans)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189562(v=sql.105).aspx) which will allow you to perform the analysis you require.

Comment: @ChrisPickford they are logically identical queries, the query engine can probably work that out and generate identical plans for both of them.

Comment: @ChrisPickford is correct, the `Distinct` should be removed. But I think the query analyser is smart enough here to remove it for you. Have a look at the execution plans, I think they will be equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn on query execution plan and look how was your query executing:
[image: Query execution plan]

Also, you can turn on client statistics and get total execution time:

[image: Statistics]

So, using these instruments you can compare different queries, and select better one.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @WakaChewbacca glad to help, don't foreg to read more about query execution plans - it's really very important information

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exists Which can do a far better job..

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as NumofAccounts 
FROM Accounts a
WHERE Deleted = 0 
AND exists ( SELECT Account_ID FROM Tasks  t WHERE t.Deleted = 0 and t.account_id=a.account_id) ;
```

When You say Efficiency,you need to narrow down to few areas like

1.Execution time needs to be improved
2.query consuming more cpu
3.using more memory

if your efficiency is related to Execution time,above query can work far better..

Your two queries may work differently based on several factors like indexes available on those tables,execution plan choosen

Comment: Not really, should generate the same execution plan.